# How to select multiple records from table in hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to get multiple values from a web page form and search the value from databate using hibernate query and retrieve the result and display it in a new page.

[image]

I need to get these text fields and even if any of the field is empty, I need to run a search query in database via controller and return set of results in a new page. I tried to store the result in array list of ArrayList but it didnt work. Could anyone please help me?

I am trying to get the text values from from web page in controller:

```
String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
String speciality = request.getParameter("speciality");
String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
```

I have Doctor's table which has all these texts fields stored. Lastname, firstname, gender, speciality. I have a class named doctor which links to the database.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="DOCTOR_DETAILS")
public class Doctor {

  @Id
  @Column (nullable=false)
  private int npi;
  @Column (nullable=false)
  private String firstName;
  @Column (nullable=false)
  private String lastName;
  @Column (nullable=false)
  private String gender;
  @Column (nullable=false)
  private String speciality;
  public int getNpi() {
    return npi;
  }
  public void setNpi(int npi) {
    this.npi = npi;
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getGender() {
    return gender;
  }
  public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  public String getSpeciality() {
    return speciality;
  }
  public void setSpeciality(String speciality) {
    this.speciality = speciality;
  } 

}
```

I need to run a select query to retrieve the records from table. Even if any of the 4 fields are empty, the query should retrieve the records.

```
try {
  begin();
  ArrayList <String> cntList = new ArrayList<String>();
  Query q = getSession().createQuery("select * from   
  doctor where lastName = :lastName or firstName =:firstName or    
  gender=:gender or speciality = :speciality");
  q.setString("username", username);
  cntList = (ArrayList<String>) q.list();
  commit();
  return cntList;
}
```

I tried the below way of using Hibernate criteria, but I am getting an error. Am I going wrong anywhere?.

I wrote below code in my controller:

[image]

Below part in my DAO class which connects to the database.

[image]

But I am  getting below error:

[image]

Could you please help me out?

The code worked fine and returned the list of results. I tried to follow the steps provided in tutorial point site, but I am getting a cast error.
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to doctor.

A type mismatch asking me to change 
Doctor doctor = iterator.next();
to 
int doctor = iterator.next();

which is something weird, since I cannot retrieve values from Doctor class.

[image]

Comment: "Even if any of the 4 fields are empty, the query should retrieve the records." What record you want to bring then? All available doctors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Hibernate criteria query with disjunction. It's been designed to handle this sort of situations. Try this code snippet

```
    public List<Doctor> getSearchResult(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String speciality, Session session) {
      Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Doctor.class);
      Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();

      if (firstName != null)
        or.add(Restrictions.ilike("firstName", firstName+"%"));
      if (lastName != null)
        or.add(Restrictions.ilike("lastName", "%"+lastName));
      if (gender != null)
        or.add(Restrictions.eq("gender", gender));
      if (speciality != null)
        or.add(Restrictions.ilike("speciality", "%"+speciality+"%"));

      cr.add(or);

      return (List<Doctor>) cr.list();
    }
```

You can get idea about Hibernate Criteria queries [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm).

Comment: I tried Hibernate Criteria query. But I am getting below error. I have specified my code and errors along with my question. Could u please help me out.

Comment: Seems like a naming miss match. Are you sure you are using the exact POJO of Doctor you've posted in the ques? Try double checking for spelling. Also check if there's actually a column in your `DOCTOR_DETAILS` table named `speciality`.

Comment: thanks a lot. You are right the column name for speciality was wrong. I changed it and it worked fine and returned the list. But now I am getting weird cast error. This is my final step. Can you help me..

Comment: That's weird! Try casting `iterator.next()` to `Doctor`.

Comment: I already tried that.. No luck, it still has cast error, Cannot cast from into to Doctor.. Is there any other way to see the contents in the list?..

Comment: Use generics. `Iterator<Doctor> it = docList.iterator()` No need to cast here.

Comment: Im getting below error,

The Type Descriptor.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parametrized with the arguments <Doctor>.

Comment: Which version of JDK are you using? Make sure you use `import java.util.Iterator;`. There can be iterator from other packages imported by autoimport and cause such prob. If all these are okay then post everything that 'HomeController' contains. I don't see anything wrong with iterator here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the import was incorrect. Everything is working fine. Once again thank you for getting me learn a new concept.

Comment: Hi, I tried searching with different combination, somewhere logic is missing. My table has 2 set of values. First one has first name Alex, last name Furguson, gender Male. Second set has Culum,Furguson,Male as values. When I tried searching by giving firstname as alex and gender as Male, both the values are getting printed. The criteria is checking for gender and since it has male for both, it is printing both. Instead i need only first set of value that has Alex. Search should work like that. Should I use anyother criteria?

Comment: I thought you are trying to get all results that matches your search criteria. If you want to get results that have all the search criteria then you'll have to use conjunction. Simply leave out the `Disjunction` and add your `Restrictions` to the criteria directly. That'll do it. I've used Disjunction since the query you have posted in the question was ORing the conditionals. You need AND here.